# Label disappears after pass my mouse over an option in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I'm a beginner in Python and I did the following window:

[image]

I made a ComboBox but every time that I pass my mouse over an option, the label disappear like the picture. ComboBox's code is the following:

```
        combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItem(" ")
        combo.addItem("Nombre1")
        combo.addItem("Apellidos1")
        combo.addItem("Cel1")
        combo.addItem("CC1")
        combo.addItem("Nombre2")
        combo.addItem("Apellidos2")
        combo.addItem("Cel2")
        combo.addItem("CC2")
        combo.addItem("Email")
        combo.addItem("Tel")
        combo.addItem("Apto(#)")
        combo.addItem("Apto(m2)")
        combo.addItem("Vista")
        combo.addItem("Proyecto")
        combo.addItem("Ciudad")
        combo.addItem("Pais")
        combo.move(213, 40)
```

If you can help me, I'll appreciate it.